# Reflecting child element changes in the container jquery object

Tags: jquery

I have a div container which has an input and button. I want to give the input a value with jquery. After the value is set, how can I "refresh" the container so that the input has the new value:

```
<div id="loginField">
    <label>User ID
        <input type="text" id="userID" value="" />
    </label>
        <button id="submitUserId" value="accept">Continue</button>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
var container  = $('#loginField');

console.log('container[0].outerHTML  is ');
console.log(container[0].outerHTML );

container .find('#userID').val('demo');

console.log('container[0].outerHTML  is now');
console.log(container[0].outerHTML );
```

If you check your console, you can see the input has no value when printing out the container. The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/muuo417t/)

I want any change to a child element in container to refresh container so that container[0].outerHTML would include the new value for the input. E.g. Printing container before and after would look like:

```
<div id="loginField">
<label>User ID
    <input type="text" id="userID" value="">
</label>
    <button id="submitUserId" value="accept">Continue</button>
</div>
```

And after injecting the input value "demo":

```
<div id="loginField">
<label>User ID
    <input type="text" id="userID" value="demo">
</label>
    <button id="submitUserId" value="accept">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Note the input value has now changed. What's the cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. I see the jsfiddle and after the js 'demo' is in the input (I use Firefox). What you want to refresh?

Comment: I want the container object to now include the new value of the input....I have edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than use:

```
var container  = $('#loginField');

console.log('container[0].outerHTML  is ');
console.log(container[0].outerHTML );

container.find('#userID').attr('value', 'demo');

console.log('container[0].outerHTML  is now');
console.log(container[0].outerHTML );
```

Comment: Works for me!, exactly that I need

Answer (score 0):

val('demo') sets DOM's value property of INPUT element, so nothing is in "outerHTML"

Look at listing from FIREBUG console:

```
x = $('<input value="x"/>')
[<input value=​"x">​]
y = x[0]
<input value=​"x">​
y.outerHTML
"<input value="x">"
y.value
"x"
x.val("y")
[<input value=​"x">​]
y.outerHTML
"<input value="x">"
y.value
"y"
x.attr("value","z")
[<input value=​"z">​]
y.outerHTML
"<input value="z">"
y.value
"z"
```

So, it's JS/DOM behavior, to match outerHTML and value you have to set ATTRIBUTE VALUE of ELEMENT not PROPERTY VALUE OF FORM CONTROL OBJECT.

For my opinion - outerHTML is worst way to accomplish your task. It's great mistake to make your logic to be based on fluctuative and browser-defined things as certain view of elements...

Change your logic to explicit checking of required fields and/or attributes that is under your direct control.